# CMake build git submodules and its dependencies

Tags: c++, cmake, git-submodules

I am a novice in CMake,

I would like to use a C++ library **A** in my CMake project.
This library **A** is included as a git submodule and I include it in my CMakeFile using

```
add_subdirectory("extern/A")
```

which works so far.

However, my library **A** has two other dependencies **B** and **C**. They are included in the CMakeFile of library **A** using `find_package()`.

Now, I would like CMake to build these dependencies **B** and **C**, so that library **A** can use them. I want to include **B** and **C** as git submodules as well.

Simply concatenating

```
add_subdirectory("extern/B")
add_subdirectory("extern/C")
add_subdirectory("extern/A")
```

obviously doesn't work. I thought using `add_dependencies` could help here, but I couldn't find a way to make it work yet...

Is it even possible to do what I want to do here? If yes, could someone give me a hint which commands I might have to use?

Comment: It's not obvious why add_subdirectory() does not work. Do these dependencies not have a CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @drescherjm
These dependencies all have a CMakeLists.txt. 
The errors I get are

`CMake Error in extern/A/src/A/CMakeLists.txt:
  export called with target "A" which requires target "B" that is
  not in any export set.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake adding `B` as a dependency to `RootProject` where `A` needs it.

## Solution

In the following directory structure:

```
RootProject
|__ .git
|__ CMakeLists.txt
|__ src
|   |__ main.c
|   |__ ...
|
|__ vendor
    |__ A
        |__ .git
        |__ CMakeLists.txt
        |__ src
            |__ ...
```

- `RootProject` depends on `A`.
- `A` is a library that has no dependencies.

If you want to add `B` as a dependency to `A`, you would treat `A` as completely separate project from `RootProject` and add `B` directly to `A`.

The directory structure of `A` becomes:

```
A
|__ .git
|__ CMakeLists.txt
|__ src
|    |__ ...
|
|__ vendor
    |__ B
        |__ .git
        |__ CMakeLists.txt
        |__ src
            |__ ...
```

Using git submodules to "manage" the dependencies:

```bash
# Adding `B` as a dependency to `A`
cd vendor/A
mkdir -p vendor
cd vendor
git submodule add https://github.com/username/B.git
```

This will add `B` as a dependency to `A`, and not to `RootProject`.

Now simply add the following to `vendor/A/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory("vendor/B")
# ......
target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC B)
```

Also note that each of `A`, `B` and `RootProject` must have a top level `CMakeLists.txt` in order for `add_subdirectory` to work.

See also:

- [add_subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html)
- [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html)
- [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)